# Image Background in Reactnative

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native project I want to set an image as the background for full screen but I am unable to resolve the header issue I am using the component "ImageBackground" for setting the image.
I want the image for full screen.
can someone help me with that?

thanks

[image: unable to resolve header]

Answer (score 0):

- In your case `ImageBackground` should be most parent view of all the views here. It seems like your toolbar is wrapped with `ImageBackground` or with its parent.
- Another reason can be possible if your `Toolbar` has an white background, then how will this image be visible. So make `Toolbar` transparent.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you are using `React-navigation`, if so, you can modify your `StackNavigator` to not display the header:

```
createStackNavigator({
  PageName: { screen: PageName },
  // all your routes
},
{
  headerMode: 'none', --> here
})
```

You will find more informations [in the react-navigation doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Everyone for your time to answer I have solved the issue by adding some styles to my image and also making the header to null.

```
static navigationOptions={
header:null
}
```